# Urllib.request.urlopen().read not working

Tags: python-3.x

last line of code is giving error.

```py
import re
import urllib.request
url="https://www.google.com/search?q=google&tbm=fin#scso=_GYPEXIHYJs6gtQXFn7i4Aw2:0"
data=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
```

> url="https://www.google.com/search?q=google&tbm=fin#scso=_GYPEXIHYJs6gtQXFn7i4Aw2:0"
>   data=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       data=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
>     File "C:\Users\SHARM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>     File "C:\Users\SHARM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
>       response = meth(req, response)
>     File "C:\Users\SHARM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
>       'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
>     File "C:\Users\SHARM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
>       return self._call_chain(*args)
>     File "C:\Users\SHARM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)
>     File "C:\Users\SHARM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
>       raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
>   urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

I want to open the url. Url works when i open manually. I do not understand why i get this error and what does this error mean?

Answer (score 1):

The `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` error probably caused by remote server security for blocking bots user agents, changing the user-agent headers will fix this error.

```py
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url="https://www.google.com/search?q=google&tbm=fin#scso=_GYPEXIHYJs6gtQXFn7i4Aw2:0" 
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
data=urlopen(req).read()
```

Comment: Very clearly explained thanks for it. How close the pop ups in website when open through urllib library?